# spullara mustache java partials

Tags: java, mustache, partials

I'm having trouble finding examples of how to implement partials using the Spullara Mustache java implementation. Their github page doesn't seem to have any straight forward partial examples.

In DefaultMustacheFactory I see methods for compilePartial and resolvePartialPath, but I'm not sure if I am supposed to override them or what.

I currently have this, and it works great without partials. TemplateContent contains the raw template html including mustache syntax.

```
    public Mustache compileMustacheTemplate(String templateCode, String templateContent){
        return new DefaultMustacheFactory().compile(new StringReader(templateContent),templateCode);
    }
```

Pretty straight forward. But what if template content had {{>partialName}} inside it? I think I need to somehow specify that template content as well.

Do I need to extend DefaultMustacheFactory or possibly another class to specify the name of my partial and the content for it?

I believe I'm just missing something.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your template files are stored in a folder 'src/main/resources/org/example/web/' and you have one template "page.html" file referencing two other template files 'header.html' and 'footer.html'. Your template file "page.html" should look like this:

```
{{> src/main/resources/org/example/web/header.html}}

... some content ...

{{> src/main/resources/org/example/web/footer.html}}
```

Comment: This was the strategy I ended up going with. Before my template html and partials were stored in a database, but couldn't figure out a way to load partial content that was stored in a java String after pulling from the DB. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: "Partial" content stored in a java String is no longer a partial, but a simple variable that must be set in the array of scopes or maps or whatever you use.